# I want to have a scrollbar on a text area in Tkinter, but not sure what's wrong with the following codes:

Tags: tkinter

```
            self.myfrm=Frame(nb, name=self.wzsgclass)
            self.myfrm.pack()
            self.sbtn = Button(self.myfrm, text='Update', underline=0,
                    command=self.update)
            self.sbtn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=7, pady=5)
            #self.txtarea=Label(self.myfrm, justify=LEFT, ancticky=W, pady=or=N, text=self.rslt)
            self.txtarea=Text(self.myfrm, width=800, height=600)
            self.txtarea.pack()
            self.txtarea.insert('3.0',self.rslt)
            self.txtarea.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
            self.vscroll = Scrollbar(self.myfrm, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.txtarea.yview)
            self.txtarea['yscroll'] = self.vscroll.set
            self.vscroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
```

I can see the button and the text area, but no scrollbar.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I tried to put the self.txtarea.pack() statement after the self.vscroll.pack(side='right', fill='y') then I can see the scrollbar, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack` works by placing objects in the available *remaining* space. When you do `self.txtarea.pack()` without arguments it is the same as `self.txtarea.pack(side="top")`. Any other widgets you pack will be *below* this widget.

Because you packed the text widget first, it used up all of the remaining space. If there was any visible space remaining, it would be below the text widget. If your window is of a fixed size, there may not have been any free visible space after packing the text widget. If the window was large enough, you would have seen the scrollbar below the text widget.

The order that you `pack` widgets matters, since each widget that is packed removes some amount of space, and any subsequent calls can only affect the remaining space. If you try to pack widgets that are too big for the space (eg: if you have a fixed window size), `pack` will start reducing windows to their smallest size before finally clipping the widget entirely. It does this in the reverse order that the widgets were packed. Since the scrollbar was last to be packed, it is the first to get removed if there's no room.

For a definitive description of the packer algorithm, see [The Packer Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26) in the official tcl/tk documentation.